How to Display Map pin labels outside the map area?
I made a map in Google My Maps, where I pointed out all my pins, annotated them, and changed their icons and colors to convey their context. All my pins are now unique. But if I zoom out, the icons are getting overlapped, and without their labels, they are just nothing but some blobs.

Even if I add a legend, you can't separate the icons from one another and can't point to the place.
Now what I want is a map where all the pins will be labeled with lines from outside the map area, like the thematic image below. I don't need the icon in this way, but the icon labels are important.

I know I can draw a map like this manually. But actually, I'm looking for an automated solution from existing applications.
How can I do that?
I am looking for a solution using any Map tool, like uMap, ArcGIS, QGIS, etc.
As I did not find the solution in either of the platforms by myself, and even with a Reddit thread I discussed earlier.
I need a solution or at least guidance to make a print-friendly Map where the pin legends will automatically be set outside the map pointing some lines to the places.

Welcome to GIS SE. Unfortunately, our Focused question/Best answer model does not work well with really broad "How do I do this in {long list of platforms}" Questions. The most frequent comments here are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" If your Question doesn't address these, it is likely to be closed. Please choose a platform and make an attempt, then [Edit] appropriately.

Thank you @Vince. I understand what you want to point out here. But I actually could not find any, I repeat any solution in any platform still now. Hence I said "solution using any Map tool". Not restricted to any platform. I Need a solution or at least guidance. BTW, I'm editing my question with some more text to clarify the intention.

You're not going to get an Answer with an any platform Question here. We don't do "solutions" or "guidance" for complex enhancement problems here. If you "Need" a solution, you probably want to engage a consultant, because I can't see any off-the-shelf solution.
